# how to use ng-repeat search filter with owl carousel without braking it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, owl-carousel

I am using ng-repeat to view PS4 games data from json file inside a owl carousel like that:

```
<data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: true, pagination: false, rewindNav : false}">
  <owl-carousel-item ng-repeat="game in $ctrl.games | filter: $ctrl.query" class="item">
                <a href="#!/games/{{game.id}}" class="thumb">
                    <img ng-src="{{game.imageUrl}}"  />
                    <p id="gamenamebox"> {{game.name}} </p>
                </a>
                <p> Genre: {{game.genre}} </p>
```

now as you can see i added a filter for $ctrl.query and just added it to a search input like that:

```
                Search for game:
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.query"/>
```

now, everything is working great, all info is in the carousel and looks like this:

[working great](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alemY.jpg)

but once i search in the search input and delete the game name i was searching for everything breaks to a line like that:

[breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F7IF.jpg)

Does anyone know how can i fix it?
Thanks in advance.

this is the javascript code by the way:

```
.directive("owlCarousel", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
          // provide any default options you want
            var defaultOptions = {
            };
            var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
            // combine the two options objects
            for(var key in customOptions) {
                defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
            }
            // init carousel
            $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
        };
    }
};
})

.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: false,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
        if(scope.$last) {
            scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: Can you add a quick plunk?

Comment: not sure what it is sorry im new to coding :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview Add your code here so we can help. Save it and share the url

Comment: Add working sample